# Testing functions returning iterable in python

Tags: python, testing, iterator

I'm having difficulties testing python functions that
return an iterable, like functions that are
yielding or functions that simply return an iterable, like `return imap(f, some_iter)` or `return permutations([1,2,3])`.

So with the permutations example, I expect the output of the function to be `[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), ...]`. So, I start testing my code.

```
def perm3():
  return permutations([1,2,3])

# Lets ignore test framework and such details
def test_perm3():
  assertEqual(perm3(), [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), ...])
```

This will not work, since `perm3()` is an iterable, not a
list. So we can fix this particular example.

```
def test_perm3():
  assertEqual(list(perm3()), [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), ...])
```

And this works fine. But what if I have nested iterables? That is
iterables yielding iterables? Like say the expressions
`product(permutations([1, 2]), permutations([3, 4]))`. Now this is
probably not useful but it's clear that it will be (once unrolling the
iterators) something like `[((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (4, 3)), ...]`.
However, we can not just wrap `list` around our result, as that will only
turn `iterable<blah>` to `[iterable<blah>, iterable<blah>, ...]`. Well
of course I can do `map(list, product(...))`, but this only works for a
nesting level of 2.

So, does the python testing community have any solution for the
problems when testing iterables? Naturally some iterables can't
be tested in this way, like if you want an infinite generator, but
still this issue should be common enough for somebody to have thought
about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [KennyTM's assertRecursiveEq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3124155/190597):

```
import unittest
import collections
import itertools

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertRecursiveEq(self, first, second, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        https://stackoverflow.com/a/3124155/190597 (KennyTM)
        """
        if (isinstance(first, collections.Iterable)
            and isinstance(second, collections.Iterable)):
            for first_, second_ in itertools.izip_longest(
                    first, second, fillvalue = object()):
                self.assertRecursiveEq(first_, second_, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # If first = np.nan and second = np.nan, I want them to
            # compare equal. np.isnan raises TypeErrors on some inputs,
            # so I use `first != first` as a proxy. I avoid dependency on numpy
            # as a bonus.
            if not (first != first and second != second):
                self.assertAlmostEqual(first, second, *args, **kwargs)                

def perm3():
    return itertools.permutations([1,2,3])

class Test(TestCase):
    def test_perm3(self):
        self.assertRecursiveEq(perm3(),
            [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.argv.insert(1, '--verbose')
    unittest.main(argv = sys.argv)
```

Comment: I'll accept this because it's as good as dbw's answer. Unlike my answer you can mix `tuples`/`lists`. This answer is also just copy-paste runnable. :) But! I would be more satisfied if there was an answer where you (1) actually check that it returns an iterable (change `return permutations([1,2,3])` to `return list(permutations([1,2,3]))` should not pass **and** (2) the nested expected value should have correct types. That is changing one of the tuples to a list should not pass (change `(2, 3, 1)` to `[2, 3, 1]`).

Comment: Ah. Fair enough.  I suppose that I usually avoid testing types, and try to test interfaces instead.  This lets implementation details change in some ways, while continuing to produce the same data/results.

Answer (score 2):

**1. If the order of results doesn't matter**

Use [unittest.assertItemsEqual()](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertItemsEqual). This tests that the items are present in both self and reference, but ignores the order.  This works on your example one nested deep example.  It also works on a 2-deep example that I concocted.

**2. If the order of results matters**

I would suggest not ever casting the results of **perm3()** to a list. Instead, compare the elements directly as you iterate. Here's a test function that will work for your example.  I added it to a subclass of unittest.TestCase:

```
def assertEqualIterables(self, itable1, itable2):
     for ival1, ival2 in zip(itable1, itable2):
         if "__iter__" in dir(ival1):
             self.assertEqualIterables(ival1, ival2)
         else:
             self.assertEquals(ival1, ival2)
```

Use it like:

```
def test_perm3(self):
    reference = [((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (4, 3)), 
                 ((2, 1), (3, 4)), ((2, 1), (4, 3)),]

    self.assertEqualIterables(perm3(), reference)
```

Comment: Has anybody else noticed assertItemsEqual working on several deep nests of iterators? I wasn't actually expecting it to work... Am I being crazy?

Answer (score 1):

You could extend you suggestion to include `type` (that was allowing you to distinguish between lists, tuples, etc.), like so:

```
def unroll(item):
  if "__iter__" in dir(item):
    return map(unroll, item), type(item)
  else:
    return item, type(item)
```

For example:

```
got = unroll(permutations([1,2]))
([([(1, <type 'int'>), (2, <type 'int'>)], <type 'tuple'>), ([(2, <type 'int'>), (1, <type 'int'>)], <type 'tuple'>)], <type 'itertools.permutations'>)
# note the final: <type 'itertools.permutations'>
expected = [(1, 2), (2, 1)]
assertEqual(x[0], unroll(expected) ) # check underlying
assertEqual(x[1], type(permutations([]) ) # check type
```

.

One thing to mention, `type` is coarse in distinguishing between *objects* e.g. `<type 'classobj'>`...

Comment: I'd prefer `isinstance()` over `type()`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I was thinking as I posted/left work, there was a better way :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any standard way python programmers test iterables, but you
can simply apply your idea of `map` and `list` into a recursive function
working for any level of nestedness.

```
def unroll(item):
  if "__iter__" in dir(item):
    return map(unroll, item)
  else:
    return item
```

Then your test will actually work.

```
def test_product_perms():
  got = unroll(product(...))
  expected = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [4, 3]], ...]
  assertEqual(got, expected)
```

However there is a flaw with this as you can see. When unrolling something, it
will always be turned to an array, this was desireable for iterables but it
also applies to the tuples. So therfore I had to manually convert the tuples in the expected result to lists. Hence, you can't diffrentiate if outputs are lists or tuples.

Another problem with this naive approach is that a passing test doesn't mean
that the function work. Say that you check `assertEqual(list(my_fun()), [1, 2,
3])`, while you think it might return an iterable that when "listed" is
equal to `[1, 2, 3]`. It might be that it did not return an iterable as you
wanted, it might have returned a list or a tuple too!